# Convert PHP RegEx to Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I have this PHP regex for remove utf8 special characters from strings:

```
[\x00-\x1F]|\xC2[\x80-\x9F]|\xE2[\x80-\x8F]{2}|\xE2\x80[\xA4-\xA8]|\xE2\x81[\x9F-\xAF]
```

I need to convert it to Javascript regex.
I tryed this code:

```
str = str.replace(/[\x00-\x1F]|\xC2[\x80-\x9F]|\xE2[\x80-\x8F]{2}|\xE2\x80[\xA4-\xA8]|\xE2\x81[\x9F-\xAF]/g, '');
```

But it does nothing.

I need your help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Simple mistake, big effect:

```
strTest = strTest.replace(/your regex here/g, "$1");
// ----------------------------------------^
```

without the "global" flag, the replace occurs for the first match only.

Side note: To remove any character that *does not fulfill* some kind of complex condition, like falling into a set of certain Unicode character ranges, you can use negative lookahead:

```
var regex = /(?![\x00-\x7F]|[\xC0-\xDF][\x80-\xBF]|[\xE0-\xEF][\x80-\xBF]{2}|[\xF0-\xF7][\x80-\xBF]{3})./g;
strTest = strTest.replace(regex, "")
```

where `regex` reads as

```
(?!      # negative look-ahead: a position *not followed by*:
  […]    #   any allowed character range from above
)        # end lookahead
.        # match this character (only if previous condition is met!)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
str = str.replace(/[\x00-\x1F]|\xC2[\x80-\x9F]|\xE2[\x80-\x8F]{2}|\xE2\x80[\xA4-\xA8]|\xE2\x81[\x9F-\xAF]/gi, '');
```